# Not able to deploy war file in jboss app server 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss

Created a spring boot project and generate the war file using maven command.
    Trying to deploy the war file in jboss eap server 7.

it shows below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sampletesting/SampleDataSourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sampleEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/sampletesting/SampleDataSourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sampleEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Please guide me to overcome this issue shown

Comment: You've got a bean wiring issue.  The exception is clear: you don't have a bean configured that is being called for.

Answer (score 0):

as [question mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401041/spring-boot-multiple-databse-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-entitymanagerfactorybu):

`@Primary` annotation must be used, one bean among the required types.